# Submit form on window close?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

Could anyone show me how to submit a form over two pages where, if the form is closed on the second page this will still automatically submit the first page's info?

E.g.

Page 1:
Full Name
Email 
Phone Number

User clicks submit...

Page 2:
Thanks for submitting your details please select a call back time..

The user would then either close the window or enter a call back time and press submit but I would need the original info to be submitted even if they close the window on the second page and do not enter a call back time.

I was thinking maybe of maybe using session variables to store the info then possibly javascript/jquery to submit the form if the window was closed?

Could anyone suggest the best was to do this?

I should probably mention as well I am inserting the data into a MySQL table then posting the data using CURL. So I could quite easily insert into the database then just do an update statement on the last id if the call back time is submitted.

But I don't know how to post the last MySQL record if the window is closed on the second form page?

Comment: Your best bet is to actually submit the data on page 1, and on page 2 submit modify/add/exchange the data as needed. Theres really no need to get too clever here, imho.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() { 
    $("#form-submit").click();
});
```

where #form-submit is the ID of your submit-button.

Answer (score 1):

The `beforeunload` event fires whenever the user leaves your page for any reason.

For example, it will be fired if the user submits a form, clicks a link, closes the window (or tab), or goes to a new page using the address bar, search box, or a bookmark.

You could exclude form submissions and hyperlinks (except from other frames) with the following code:

```
var inFormOrLink;
$('a').live('click', function() { inFormOrLink = true; });
$('form').bind('submit', function() { inFormOrLink = true; });

$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() { 
    return inFormOrLink || confirm("Do you really want to close?"); 
})
```

The `live` method doesn't work with the submit event, so if you add a new form, you'll need to bind the handler to it as well.

Note that if a different event handler cancels the submit or navigation, you will lose the confirmation prompt if the window is actually closed later. You could fix that by recording the time in the `submit` and `click` events, and checking if the `beforeunload` happens more than a couple of seconds later.

Comment: Good start, but confirm("..."); during beforeunload is not allowed and will be ignored. You should just return the text you want to be displayed in the confirmation box, like "return 'Do you really want to close?';"

Answer (score 0):

You can't really.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() { 
    // Do submit here
});
```

Might seem to work, but

a) regular form submits (i.e. redirects to another page with POST or GET) are not allowed during the beforeunload phase, so will not work.

b) AJAX form submits *will* fire, but you are never sure they will arrive, because the browser  will not wait for the callback to happen, but will simply close the window after your code has run.

Comment: Going off of **b)**, as soon as the browser fires off the AJAX request, it will finish the `beforeunload` function and leave. Once it leaves, most browsers will abort the AJAX request, and that may or may not stop it from reaching the server or whatever

Comment: Good addition. Didn't know that running requests would be actively cancelled. How does that work? Because the request has already been fired, how will a cancel action stop a request from reaching the server?

Comment: I really wish I knew, I never understood that. I don't know if it sends something to the server and says "Don't bother responding to that last request" and/or "Don't process that last request", but I don't know how the server would actually handle that anyways. And I actually never bothered testing. You're right though, that the browser won't know if everything was successful/error because it won't have time to receive the response.

Comment: Yeah exactly.... Well, *if* at anytime I find out and remember this thread, I'll post an update :)